# Nonblocking texture upload on iPhone and other OpenGL ES platforms

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

I am doing some work which involves drawing video frames in real time in OpenGL ES. Right now I am using glTexImage2D to transfer the data, in the absence of Pixel Buffer Objects and the like. A below answer suggests that glTexImage2D is always blocking, even if texture object referenced does is not used for any drawing. Is there a way to do a nonblocking texture upload with OpenGL ES (any version)?

Thank you very much, Sean

Answer (score 0):

No, glTexImage2D blocks, and will not return until the copy is complete.

I'm not sure if GL ES supports context sharing, if it does, you can upload the texture in another thread with another context, sharig that texture with your main context.